# Get links from a site's homepage using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to write a script to get a home page's links to social media (twitter / facebook mostly), and I'm completely stuck since I am fairly new to Python.

The task I want to accomplish is to parse the website, find the social media links, and save it in a new data frame where each column would contain the original URL, the twitter link, and the facebook link. Here's what I have so far of this code for the new york times website:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "http://www.nytimes.com"
r = requests.get(url)
sm_sites = ['twitter.com','facebook.com']

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
all_links = soup.find_all('a', href = True)


for site in sm_sites:
    if all(site in sm_sites for link in all_links):
        print(site)
    else:
        print('no link')
```

I'm having some problems understanding what the loop is doing, or how to make it work for what I need it to. I also had tried to store the site instead of doing `print(site)` but that was not working... So I figured I'd ask for help. Before asking, I went through a bunch of responses here but none could get me to do what I needed to do.

Comment: Your `if` statement doesn't do anything useful. It checks if each element of the list `sm_sites` is in the lsit `sm_sites`, whichc is clearly always true and completely irrelevant. What did you want this condition to check for?

Comment: @jacoblaw I wanted to write something that would let me check whether each of the sites in `sm_sites` is in `all_links`. Then there's the additional step that I want to do (and have no idea how to write it in python) that I want to store the full link to their twitter and facebook as columns in a pandas DF. Ideally, I want this code to do these things for several websites (but figured that's what loops are for so I can just write a loop around this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the way this code works, you already have your links. Your homepage link is the starting `url`, so `http://www.nytimes.com`.
And you have the social media urls `sm_sites = ['twitter.com','facebook.com']`, all you're doing is confirming they exist on the main page. If you want to save the list of confirmed social media urls, then append them to a list

Here is one way to get the social media links off a page

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python"
r = requests.get(url)
sm_sites = ['twitter.com','facebook.com']
sm_sites_present = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
all_links = soup.find_all('a', href = True)


for sm_site in sm_sites:
    for link in all_links:
        if sm_site in link.attrs['href']:
            sm_sites_present.append(link.attrs['href'])

print(sm_sites_present)
```

output:

```
['https://twitter.com/stackoverflow', 'https://www.facebook.com/officialstackoverflow/']
```

**Update**
for a df of urls

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from IPython.display import display

urls = [
    "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python",
    "https://www.nytimes.com/",
    "https://en.wikipedia.org/"
]

sm_sites = ['twitter.com','facebook.com']
sm_sites_present = []
columns = ['url'] + sm_sites
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'url' : urls}, columns=columns)

def get_sm(row):
    r = requests.get(row['url'])
    output = pd.Series()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
    all_links = soup.find_all('a', href = True)
    for sm_site in sm_sites:
        for link in all_links:
            if sm_site in link.attrs['href']:
                output[sm_site] = link.attrs['href']
    return output

sm_columns = df.apply(get_sm, axis=1)
df.update(sm_columns)
df.fillna(value='no link')
```

output [image]

Comment: Oh this is extremely helpful! I have two questions. One, how can I put `sm_sites_present` in a pandas DF where each `sm_site` is a column and the `url` is the first column? Two, how can I append something saying `no link` in this DF when there are no links?

Comment: oh... i just read the first part... try using `df.fillna(value="no link")`. *edit* I included it

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want with regards to adding it to a DataFrame. You can iterate through a list of websites (urlsToSearch), adding a row to the dataframe for each one containing the base website, all facebook links, and all twitter links.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Website", "Facebook", "Twitter"])

urlsToSearch = ["http://www.nytimes.com","http://www.businessinsider.com/"]

for url in urlsToSearch:
    r = requests.get(url) 

    tw_links = []
    fb_links = []

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    all_links = [link['href'] for link in soup.find_all('a', href = True)] #only get href

    for link in all_links:
        if "twitter.com" in link:
            tw_links.append(link)
        elif "facebook.com" in link:
            fb_links.append(link)

   df.loc[df.shape[0]] = [url,fb_links,tw_links] #Add row to end of df
```